# How I could create a db with the messages that are saved in admin/reports/dblog?

Tags: database, drupal, watchdog

I want to create a table in the db with the column message and with values from column message on admin/reports/dblog...Could someone help me? Or take the message from the db but in db the messages are with separated variables :/

Comment: The table already exists, and the message is separated from the variables because it is translatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `function hook_watchdog(array $log_entry) { }` where `$log_entry` is an array with all the log data you need.

Read more: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7